# Prompted to reinstall Terraria after opening it, and character missing after reinstallation

Tags: technical-issues, terraria

I opened up Steam and went to Terraria, but instead of saying "play," like it usually does, it said "install." So I installed the game, even though I had never uninstalled it in the first place. After the install, everything was exactly the same except one of my characters was replaced with a blank character slot with 0:00 play time.

[image: WTH]

All my worlds were still there, as well as the one other player I had.
I also found a world called Unknown World and loading it causes the game to crash. It's actually the size that's unknown it has no name.
[image: help]

How can I get my character back?

Comment: Can you show screenshot with "unknown word"? In Terraria (counterpart to Minecraft or other games) characters and worlds are detached, you can create new character and enter old world without problem, so adding screenshot with characters is pointless. In general you should use cloud save to ensure you won't loose data. More likely you have data corrupted (e.g. due to power failure) that's why Steam offer you to install a game (as it was never installed). Happens sometimes to HDD and SSD.

Comment: please tell me if you know, isn't there any way I can dig through the game files to find the existing players? nothing happened that could have led to this. I did NOTHING to the game files. I'm sorry but the reply wasn't all that helpful and I need an answer if you have one. you're right that I should have saved it to the cloud but it's too late now unless I know how to get it back.

Answer (score 1):

Well as I can't comment... I will try to help you as much as I can from what you have written. It seems you are not the only one having this issue. On the official Terraria forums there was a discussion about it and how to possibly get your character/world back. [Here](https://forums.terraria.org/index.php?threads/my-entire-character-is-gone.22498/) is a thread that was discussing this.

To make it easier so you don't want to read it all.

1. There was a suggestion to look into your file with saved characters (if you had not saved them on cloud) and you should see 2 files with your characters name, one PLR and one PLR.BAK. Delete the PLR file and rename the PLR.BAK to PLR and you may see your character again.
2. If you don't have your character name in here check the Recycle bin if it did not delete itself (there was a bug causing save files to delete themselves)
3. If you get your files back from the recycle bin and still can't access them you can try to edit them in the Terraria editor.